# os.path.exists возвращает False, при этом путь правильный

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.8

Система: win7x64, Python 3.8

Нужно было проверить находится ли файл по указанному пути(файл там находится 100%)

```py
import subprocess
import os

python = subprocess.check_output('where python', shell=True).decode("utf-8")
print(os.path.exists(python))
```

Но почему-то вместо True я получаю False. Далее я попробовал указать сразу путь(тот же):

```py
import subprocess
import os

python = subprocess.check_output('where python', shell=True).decode("utf-8")
print(os.path.exists("C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"))
```

На что в этот раз я получил `True`. Я попробовал просто сравнить с помощью `if`:

```py
import subprocess
import os

python = subprocess.check_output('where python', shell=True).decode("utf-8")

if (python == r"C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

И тут также False. Т.е. строка не ровняется указанному значению?
Я также выводил строки с помощью print():

```py
import subprocess
import os

python = subprocess.check_output('where python', shell=True).decode("utf-8")

print(os.path.exists(python))
print(r"C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe")
print(python )
```

Вывод:

```noe
False
C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
```

и проверял их тип с помощью `type()`, строки полностью одинаковые. Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Там где не нужны низкоуровнивые операции очень хорошо работает модуль pathlib. При этом сравниваются пути, а не строки.
`pathlib.Path('.').resolve() == pathlib.Path.cwd().resolve()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все объясняется просто и в этом нет магии. При проверке вывода вы получаете строку с переводами строк или возможно другими символами, т.е. что-то такое

```
C:\\Python39\\python.exe\r\n
```

Почистите это, например так

```py
python = python.strip()
```

Режет глаз название переменной

```py
path_to_python = python.strip()
```

**Офтоп**
Чтобы найти путь до текущего интерпретатора можете восползоваться этим

```py
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это действительно помогло! Откуда в конце появляются эти символы (я их замечал при создании списка)? И почему при выводе через print() они не выводятся?

Comment: @dan_oasis легко понять при использовании `print()` если у вас есть пустая строка в конце или несколько строк. Для того чтобы понять, что происходит сделайте так `print(python.__repr__())`

Answer (score 3):

Там в конце еще перевод строки. Его нужно убрать

```
print(os.path.exists(python.rstrip())) 
# rstrip() удаляет пробелы, табуляторы и пр. в конце строки
```

---

> И тут также False. Т.е. строка не ровняется указанному значению?

То есть да, строки не равны. То, что на печати строки ***выглядят*** одинаково, не означает, что они и в самом деле одинаковы.